# Can I call a PHP function in a JavaScript click handler?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login system and I would like to introduce a feature where the user can change his email...

However if I click change the site reloads and nothing happens.

Here is the script in the function:

```
function changeemail($newemail, $mysqli) { 
    $sql="UPDATE members SET email = '$newemail' WHERE userid='$_SESSION[user_id]"; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param(); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close(); 
}
```

And here's the html part:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"> 
    <input type="text" id="newemail"><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Ändern!" onclick="return changeemail(this.form,
          this.form.newemail);"/>       
</form><br>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cant call a php function via a js onclick

Comment: As @Dagon noted, PHP us a server-side language; javascript is client- (browser-)side. You're mixing oil and water.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling ohh I see... But I must call this function somehow...

Comment: @LynnCrumbling *Javascript is client side (you typo'd php there)

Comment: why not just use the regular form submit then

Comment: @Dagon  I am a bit confused now... What can I do to fix it?

Comment: @TheCrazyLex Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php -- you don't need to define a function; you can access it via `$_POST['newemail']`

Comment: @TheCrazyLex Terrific - you may want to post an answer to your own question, then... especially if you've got it working. Amazingly, you've attracted downvotes, but no close votes yet. Post a working answer, and I'll +1 it. Start by answering the question posed in your title.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling ok, I made it :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call a php function from a javascript onclick, because php is a serverside language and javascript a client side.

I don't need a function at all, because I can get the value, entered in the form, by POST.

Answer (score 0):

Since php is server side you can not do that. But what you could do is use Javascript/jquery to load in a page onclick and then update the email

Then use Javascript to upload the page

```
 $( "#result" ).load("yourpage.php");
```